# In DQN, how to increase epsilon but not too much?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, exploration-exploitation-tradeoff, epsilon-greedy-policy, exploration-strategies

I am using DQN algorithm in a non-stationary problem in a continuous learning. My environment gives me some new states each T steps. For example after 10 000 steps, I get some new states and I need to train it again but not from zero. I need to change just epsilon to discover some new states in a way that I don't lose my previous experiences. In other words, how to increase epsilon but not too much? I don't want a fixed epsilon_0 like 1 or 0.99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the value of `epsilon` during training, for example, by using a *linear decay schedule* as a function of the steps or every `T` of them: you start from an *initial epsilon* (e.g. $\epsilon_0 = 1$) and decay with some factor (e.g. $\gamma_\epsilon = 1/T$) until a minimum/final value of epsilon is reached (e.g. $\epsilon_\min = 0.1$).

The rule is something like:
$$\epsilon \leftarrow \max\big(\epsilon_\min, \epsilon - (\epsilon_0 - \epsilon_\min) * \gamma_\epsilon\big) $$

In practice you start with high epsilon so that your agent explores a lot initially, then you start to decrease it gradually until it reaches a minimum value, after that your agent mostly exploits (indeed if final $\epsilon=0$ that it only exploits.)

Moreover, if you want to periodically increase $\epsilon$ but not to the max value each time, you can decay $\epsilon_0$ too: for example, you can $\epsilon_0\leftarrow \epsilon_0*\gamma_\epsilon$ every `T` steps and then proceed with the linear decay. It would be like resetting the epsilon from time to time, and then gradually decrease that to favor exploitation.